# JS detect mobile & desktop width & resize AND reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, resize

I have a function that detects the window width and based on that does jquery things that mobile would have and does jquery things for desktop. I have two functions, one that alters content resize and one on reload. What I am trying to do is combine the two into one function. The problem now is anything in the resize function just resizes. Even `$("html").width();`

Anyone have any ideas or solutions? Thanks.

```
//ON RESIZE 
$(window).resize(function () {clearTimeout(this.id);this.id = setTimeout(checkTimer, 500);});
function checkTimer() {
    var width = $(window).width();
//MOBILE
    if (width < 640) {
        mobileView();
    }
//TABLET
    else if (width > 640 && width <966) {
        appendFix();        
    }
//DESKTOP
    else if (width >966) {
        appendFix();
    }
};
//ON RELOAD 
    var width2 = $(window).width();
//MOBILE
    if (width2 < 640) {
        mobileView();
    };
//TABLET
    if (width2 > 640 && width2 <966) {
        appendFix();
    };
//DESKTOP
    if (width2 > 966) {
        appendFix();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the solution.

```
$(window).resize(function () {clearTimeout(this.id);this.id = setTimeout(mobileSize, 500);});
    function mobileSize() {
        sizes();
    }
    $(window).load(function() {
        sizes(); 
    });
function sizes() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width < 640) {

        }
        else if (width > 640 && width < 966) {

        }
        else if (width > 966) {

        }
    }
```